# Google cloud storage to Bigquery data upload and dynamic table creation with auto schema detection using python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How to upload data from google cloud storage to big query and create table dynamically by auto detecting schema from uploaded csv file???

I used below code but i need to define schema everytime. How can i get auto schema detection for creating table and inserting data

Code using currently:

```
import numpy as np
import uuid
from gcloud import bigquery


def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    if table.exists():
        table.delete()
    table.schema = (
        bigquery.SchemaField('ID', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('days', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('last_activ_date', 'STRING'),


    )

    table.create()
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, source)

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
        job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))

def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_data_from_gcs('my_model','my_output', 'gs://path-
uat/data_project/my_output.csv')
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2926